# What is the proper naming convention for instance variables?

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions

In my introductory programming course, my teacher always uses the following naming convention when declaring instance variables in his code:

```
public class Snowman {
    private Ellipse _top;
    private Ellipse _middle;
    private Ellipse _bottom;

public Snowman() {
        _top = new Ellipse();
        _top.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        _top.setFrameColor(Color.BLACK);
        _top.setFrameThickness(1);
        _top.setSize(80, 80);
        _middle = new Ellipse();
        _middle.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        _middle.setFrameColor(Color.BLACK);
        _middle.setFrameThickness(1);
        _middle.setSize(120, 120);
        _bottom = new Ellipse();
        _bottom.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        _bottom.setFrameColor(Color.BLACK);
        _bottom.setFrameThickness(1);
        _bottom.setSize(160, 160);
    }
}
```

In the course textbook, however, instance variables do not start with an underscore, but rather follow the same naming convention as that of primitive type variables (`int revolutionsPerMinute`). When I did an online search, I found several sources, including the online Javadoc, that cited the same convention as my textbook. As I could not reproduce the naming conventions my teacher follows, I am skeptical as to whether his convention is legitimate. Is the convention taught my teacher even existant, if not widely accepted?

Comment: This is pretty much up to you, or your boss :)  There's several conventions, you'll probably make your own dialect, and that will be one more on the list.

Comment: Ask [the experts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).  It is the JLS you are after.

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned in my post, I looked over the documentation. I was curious as to whether the said naming convention existed at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally the standard convention in Java is **camel case** where you start the variable with lower case and using upper case for the first letter of every other word. For example:

```
int myVariable; 
int mySecondVariable;
```

But note that these are conventions not rules. So anyone is free to use any convention, but it is recommended to use the standard convention to make the code **readable** for anyone.

Comment: Note: The convention on [instance] variable names tends to be a little "more lax" than it is on method names and classnames. (That is, code can get away with `int m_sillyConvention` much more than it can get away with `void do_stuff()` or `class hurtzMahEyez`.)

Answer (score 4):

**Class names and Types**

First caps: `SomeClassName`, `URL` (acronym)

**Static, Instance Variables and Methods**

Camel case: `thisIsCamelCase`.

**Constants**

All caps: `A_CONSTANT`

**Packages**

All lowercase: `javax.swing.jfilechooser`

Comment: For acronyms, the "official" Java style is all caps if <= 3 characters and init caps otherwise (eg `HttpURLConnection`), but event that isn't consistent (see `SslRMIServerSocketFactory`). A pretty common alternative, which I personally prefer, is to init cap all acronyms.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say convention is something that you follow while writing your code for the ease of the writing of the code. I don't think there is anything such as existent or non-existent convention. However, the classes you make may be used by other programmers too. So, they might have problems if they don't know the convention that you have followed. It is therefore suggested that you follow the naming convention followed by most java programmers:

```
int myFirstNumber;
ClassName objectName;
```

So, it is up to you to select the convention but I recommended following the standard that has been mentioned in the javadoc and your textbook.

Answer (score 0):

no big deal with a leading underscore.

as long as it doesn't start with a capital letter - that will completely confuse java programmers.